# matlab's out of memory error

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

I try to run the following code on matlab:

```
syms a c mu epsi real
epsi=10


eq_1=(0.5*pi^2-mu+2*epsi)*a+2*epsi*c-0.25*(3*a^3+3*a^2*c+6*a*c^2);
eq_2=(4.5*pi^2-mu+2*epsi)*c+2*epsi*a-0.25*(a^3+6*a^2*c+3*c^3);
[a_mu  c_mu ]=solve(eq_1,eq_2,a,c)

N_prime=diff(0.5*(a_mu.^2+c_mu.^2),mu)
```

and I get the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> eq
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in ==> sym.sym>char2sym at 377
if isempty(x) || all(x == ' ') || strcmp(x,'{}')

Error in ==> sym.sym at 95
   S = char2sym(x);

Error in ==> sym.maple at 92
   result = sym(result,'keepijalias');

Error in ==> sym.diff at 50
   R = reshape(maple('map','diff',S(:),x),size(S));

Error in ==> Untitled4 at 10
N_prime=diff(0.5*(a_mu.^2+c_mu.^2),mu)
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: did you read the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html)? I get a solution on R2015a without any memory issues.

Comment: yes. I read it couple of times . what should I do first?I run it on windows 7 32 bits.

Comment: which matlab version are you using? you could try restarting matlab and then just run the code you posted, does this work?

Comment: im using R2007b. I tryed restarting it didnt work

Comment: upgrading might help then

Comment: cant I solve it with my current matlab version?

Comment: It also may be the fact that you're working on a 32-bit operating system.... also, R2007b is pretty old.  I would also recommend you upgrade to a more recent version.  There have been lots of advancements with the software since 2007.